# Guarantee to be thread safe in j2ee

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, ejb-3.1

i use it this design pattern in j2ee :

```
public class myClass{
  private static Hashtable<Integer, ContentClass> contents = new Hashtable<Integer, ContentClass>();
public synchronized static void m1(){
//some work on contents

}
public synchronized static void m2(){
//another some work on contents

}
```

I want to deploy this in 3 server that run `glassfish`.

**Quiz 1 :** is it guarantee to be thread safe?

**Quiz 2 :** if the class change to Stateful EJB what happened? is it thread safe?

Comment: Not only it is *not* thread-safe, but the `Hashtable contents` will be different per server. Not only per server as a physical/virtual machine, but per JVM - meaning that even if the applications run on the same "machine" but on different server instances, there will be (a) no thread safety guranteed and (b) `contents` will be different. You may want to look at distributed caching solutions (e.g. Ehcache, Hazelcast, Infinispan).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Thanks. if you think this program run only in one jvm what situation is occurs? distributed caching solutions is not automatically in glassfish ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share a bean between three servers that run glashfish, you need to use EJB persistence with **entity beans, not use stateless nor stateful session beans**. But EJB persistence will not work with static members.

Thus, you should write:

```
public class myClass{
  private Hashtable<Integer, ContentClass> contents = new Hashtable<Integer, ContentClass>();
  public synchronized void m1(){
//some work on contents

}
public synchronized void m2(){
  //another some work on contents
}
```

and add annotations or other means to explain the container how to persist `contents` with some kind of mapping.

This way, you can persist this entity bean to a shared data source, and the three servers will be able to access it correctly. So, you need to define a data source, a persistence unit and an entity manager to manage this bean's instances.

This way, your code will be thread-safe. Accessing `contents` will be correctly done.

Comment: Very thanks. your answer very useful for me and show me the new approach.